# Could not find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypeEntryTypeNameOffset"

Tags: unix, jmap

I execute for following:

```
jmap -heap 23054
```

But I get an error. The output is:

```
Attaching to process ID 23054, please wait...
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.NoSuchSymbolException: Could not find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypeEntryTypeNameOffset" in any of the known library names (libjvm.so, libjvm_g.so, gamma_g)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.lookupInProcess(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:400)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.getLongValueFromProcess(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:381)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.readVMTypes(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:86)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.<init>(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:68)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.setupVM(BugSpotAgent.java:550)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.go(BugSpotAgent.java:476)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.attach(BugSpotAgent.java:314)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:146)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JMap.main(JMap.java:126)
Debugger attached successfully.
jmap requires a java VM process/core!
```